# sql query : showing all rows with groupBy clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to show all table rows when using a groupBy clause?
exp :

```
id      user_id   gift_id  
 1        1          1     
 2        1          2     
 3        1          1    
 4        2          3    
 5        2          1    
 6        3          4
```

expected result: (after counting by user_id)

```
id      user_id   gift_id   count 
 1        1          1       3
 2        1          2       3
 3        1          1       3
 4        2          3       2
 5        2          1       2
 6        3          4       1
```

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Comment: He wants all rows not merged

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select a.*, b.user_count from tablename as a join 
(select user_id, count(*) as user_count from tablename group by user_id) as b on
a.user_id= b.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
     , user_id
     , gift_id
     , Count(user_id) over (PARTITION BY user_id) nb_user_id
FROM matable
```